# Print a code128C barcode pair

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

The bar code 128 subset C the number of digits should always be even. 
How to print bar code with odd character? example:

```
1517072011170323703007607271023031701
```

Using DelhiXE7 and Fortes Report 4.0 VCL

Comment: Apparently, you should add a leading zero: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T255219/barcode-code128-with-character-set-c-text-length-even-and-odd-length. I suggest you ask a meta question somewhere else on how to use Google.

Answer (score 0):

Is this question related to finnish banking barcode ?

if YES: You must pad the data to be of even length, according to the documentation published by the bank. Switching the barcode encoding system is not allowed by the relevant banking standard.

reference URL:  http://www.finanssiala.fi/maksujenvalitys/dokumentit/Bank_bar_code_guide.pdf

if NO: Just first encode the even-length part, then switch to code 128A or 128B using the encoding switching special "character" and finally encode the last digit using either 128A or 128B, whichever serves you better.